# ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I trying to run this code snippet with my own csv file:

```
data_df = pd.read_csv("movies_genres_en.csv", delimiter='\t')

# split the data, leave 1/3 out for testing
data_x = data_df[['plot']].as_matrix()
data_y = data_df.drop(['title', 'plot', 'plot_lang'], axis=1).as_matrix()
stratified_split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.33)
for train_index, test_index in stratified_split.split(data_x, data_y):
    x_train, x_test = data_x[train_index], data_x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = data_y[train_index], data_y[test_index]

#data_x = overviews,
#data_y = values from all the genre types('Action','Adventure', 'Fantasy') (1 0 0 ...)
# transform matrix of plots into lists to pass to a TfidfVectorizer

train_x = [x[0].strip() for x in x_train.tolist()]
test_x = [x[0].strip() for x in x_test.tolist()]
```

I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is
>   too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less
>   than 2.

All of my instances has more value than 2
This is an info about my csv value:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4643 entries, 0 to 4642
Data columns (total 20 columns):
title              4643 non-null object
Action             4643 non-null object
Adventure          4643 non-null object
Fantasy            4643 non-null object
Science Fiction    4643 non-null object
Crime              4643 non-null object
Drama              4643 non-null object
Thriller           4643 non-null object
Animation          4643 non-null object
Family             4643 non-null object
Western            4643 non-null object
Comedy             4643 non-null object
Romance            4643 non-null object
Horror             4643 non-null object
Mystery            4643 non-null object
History            4643 non-null object
War                4643 non-null object
Music              4643 non-null object
Documentary        4643 non-null object
overview           4639 non-null object
dtypes: object(20)
memory usage: 725.5+ KB
```

Top five row of csv file:

```
data_df.head():
```

[image: here]

Comment: So wait, you're trying to predict whether something will happen when it's only happened once? The problem is in the StratifiedShuffleSplit as it'll need you to have one element of the target in each of the two splits.

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet Sorry but I can't understand your answer. In my csv if a movie tag as a genre it's value is 1 if it's not then value is 0. For example, my movie has three tagged genres and these are 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Fantasy' then its row going to be movie_name 1 1 1 0 0 .. 0 movie_overview .

Comment: could you put the top five rows of your dataset in your answer? Because to me it looks like you have a column that has the movie title and the rest of the columns are genre flags. It isn't obvious which column is your target, and that's what's causing the stratifiedSampleSplit error.

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet Sure. I edited the question

Comment: Cheers, one more, what columns are in X and what are in y?

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet X has movie overviews and y has all the thing other than title and overview basically it has genres

Comment: for supervised learning you'll need y to be one column. Maybe just re-try running the model just trying to predict whether a movie was an action movie? Otherwise you'll need to collapse those columns into one, and that'll remove the cases where a movie is both an action / romance for instance.

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet thanks a lot. I finally understand what's going on it works flawless when I tried for one genre , also I just want predict one genre at a time, it's okay for me to say action or romance if movie has tagged for this two genres. I have one final question. Can I make this kind of prediction using this split method

Comment: yep that should be fine (as long as there's more than 2 instances of that genre). Just give it a try. If that works I'll write this all up in an answer so we can close off this question

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet I use MultiLabelBinarizer() method and it worked.  You're a real life hero, thanks for everything :))

Comment: Happy to help. Can you put your descriptions of what is in X and Y in body of the question so I can give it an answer and close this question off?

Comment: @blumbus_bouquet sure. I added them to the question body, thanks again.